# onClick action to show more information html, css, javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created html and css that looks something like this:
https://jsfiddle.net/jw7pfb1w/

As you can see, I made those boxes 300px in height, but I have more information, that is hidden with `overflow: hidden;`. Now I created a button

```
//html
<a id="show-more" class="show">Show More</a>

/css
.show {
display: block;
background-color: #75868E;
width: 100px;
font-size: 12px;
text-transform: uppercase;
display: inline-block;
margin: 20px auto;
cursor: pointer;
height: 15px;
padding: 10px 0; 
}
```

And now I want to see all the information in those three boxes when I click the button. I tried something like this

I added this to css:

```
#model1.open {
max-height: 1000px;
//transitions
-webkit-transition: max-heigth 0.7s;
-moz-transition: max-heigth 0.7s;
transition: max-heigth 0.7s;
}
```

and this to javascript

```
var content = document.getElementByClassName(".model1");
var button = document.getElementById("show-more")

button.onclick = function(){

if(content.className == "open"){
    content.className = "";
    button.innerHTML = "Show More";

} else {
    content.className = "open";
    button.innerHTML = "Show Less";
}

};
```

But it does'not work. I am stuck. Can someone help me to make this work, please?

Answer (score 2):

There's a handful of bugs with your code.

- In your CSS, you refer to `model1` as an id, but in your JavaScript you
  refer to it as a class.
- `getElementByClassName` should be `getElementsByClassName` with an s after Element. You will have seen this issue if you looked in your browser console. (`ctrl` + `shift` + `i`).
- You don't include the `.` symbol in `getElementsByClassName`, so you should use the value `modal1` instead of `.modal1`.
- If you do use `getElementsByClassName`, you need to specify which element of that class to affect, otherwise all elements with that class will be effected, meaning clicking that button will show more and less of all the modals. I use jQuery, so I'm not sure what the pure JS alternative is, but you probably want to detect which .modal1 has a shared parent with the button that was clicked, or alternately put an attribute of which number button that is, and put the same attribute on the modal, and use that to tie the two elements behavior together.

This may not be a complete list of bugs, but these are the most obvious ones I see.

Answer (score 0):

If i have only one element, then it works. See > https://jsfiddle.net/075tcezL/

```
But how do i make it show or hide all three elements at the same time when i 
click the button?
```